# What is the difference between multiclass hinge loss and triplet loss?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, loss-function, multiclass-classification

The triplet loss (https://omoindrot.github.io/triplet-loss) seems very similar to the multiclass hinge loss (http://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#interpret). It is not clear what is the difference between the two.